# How to set a variable by its symbolized name

Tags: crystal-lang

I'm learning crystal (just for fun) and trying to implement kind of `[]=` method for a struct. Here is the first attempt:

```
struct Foo
  @str : String | Int32 # Have to share all the types, NOT OK
  @int : Int32 | String # Have to share all the types, NOT OK

  def initialize(@str = "foo", @int = 111)
  end

  def []=(variable, value)
    {% for ivar in @type.instance_vars %}
      @{{ivar}} = value if {{ivar.id.symbolize}} == variable
    {% end %}
  end
end

foo = Foo.new
foo[:str] = "bar" # OK
foo[:int] = 222   # OK
```

It works, but the disadvantage is all the instance variables should share the same type, otherwise the compiller will complain. My second attempt was to reimplement the method like this:

```
def []=(variable, value)
  {% for ivar in @type.instance_vars %}
    {% if ivar.id.symbolize == variable %} # ERROR: undefined macro variable 'variable'
      @{{ivar}} = value
    {% end %}
  {% end %}
end
```

But this doesn't work, as `variable` inside `{%%}` syntax can't be resolved. How to overcome this problem? Maybe there is other idiomatic approach to implement such method at all?

Comment: What's your use case? That seems highly dynamic and Crystal isn't supposed to be used like that.

Comment: @asterite, I have a struct (kind of preset) with bunch of properties and try to update other class properties with that struct properties.

Comment: Then why do you need symbols? You can just use a plain struct.

Comment: @JohannesMüller, generally, the problem I'm trying to solve, could be expressed like: http://ix.io/Fu7/crystal

Comment: Just copy each property one by one.

Comment: @asterite, I don't know, how to.  And I can't grep api docs by method name (copy) neither. Do you have any code snippet to demonstrate?

Comment: Sure, just `@a = obj.a; @b = obj.b; @c = obj.c`. Something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the instance variables to have a union of all possible types, you can restrict to the matching type in the setter method:

```
struct Foo
  @str : String
  @int : Int32

  def initialize(@str = "foo", @int = 111)
  end

  def []=(variable, value)
    {% for ivar in @type.instance_vars %}
      if {{ivar.id.symbolize}} == variable
        if value.is_a?({{ ivar.type.id }})
          @{{ivar}} = value
        else
          raise "Invalid type #{value.class} for {{ivar.id.symbolize}} (expected {{ ivar.type.id }})"
        end
      end
    {% end %}
  end
end

foo = Foo.new
foo[:str] = "bar"
foo[:int] = 222
foo[:int] = "string"  # => Invalid type String for :int (expected Int32)
```

While that is certainly possible, it comes at the disadvantage that these type mismatches are only detected at runtime. You'll get better type safety if you access the properties directly (`foo.int = "string"` will not even compile).
It should be possible to implement `[]=` as a macro which could complain at compile time about type mismatches, but I'm not sure that's what you're looking for.

A better solution might be to just use a [`NamedTuple`](https://crystal-lang.org/api/NamedTuple.html). Or maybe you don't need to access the fields using symbols at all. I don't know if there is a real use case for this.

Comment: Thank you! I think, there should be real usecases for this, e.g. Ruby has such method: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Struct.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D

Comment: Yeah, but "because Ruby has it", doesn't mean there's a real use case for this in Crystal. Ruby is a dynamically typed language, Crystal statically typed. And there is a great benefit in having static type checking.